# Set/change project language in Eclipse after project creation?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to set/change the project's language after an Eclipse project was (externally) created?

Details: I've created an Eclipse project (for a piece of software written in Java) based on the "gradle eclipse" command, which build a project that opens fine in Eclipse...but when I open files for editing, none of the syntax highlighting (and other helpful stuff you're supposed to get by using an IDE instead of barebones text editor) is there.  I've been poking around in Eclipse for hours now and haven't found a way to set the project to be a Java project.  Is there any way to tell Eclipse that the code is Java **after** the project is created?

I'm using Eclipse platform 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

http://enarion.net/programming/eclipse-change-general-to-java-project/

**Problem: Migrate a Eclipse general project to a Eclipse Java project**

You have a Eclipse project, which contains Java code – but you didn’t set it up as a Java project when you created or checked out this project. So since Eclipse doesn’t allow you to change the project type inside the Gui, you are stucked.

**Solution: add the java nature**

- Close your project.
- Open your project file (which is located in your root directory of the appropriate project) called `.project` with your default editor. Search for

  <natures>
  </natures>

and change it to

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Save the changed file.

- Open the project again – now it’s a java project.

**Edit**
After looking into this myself, it seems indeed that this is not enough. You will also need

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
```

and if that shouldn't be sufficient, maybe a minimum `.classpath` file (the easiest is probably just copy any you find in other projects, restart and correct the build path manually).

Comment: They've changed it from <natures></natures> to the XML-correct <natures/> now.  But changing this seems to have had no effect, even after restarting Eclipse.

Comment: All of my .project files (apparently there were a whole bunch created by gradle, one everywhere that it found a Java source file I think) look like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
 <name>jposee</name>
 <comment/>
 <projects/>
 <natures>
  <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
 <buildSpec>
  <buildCommand>
   <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
   <arguments/>
  </buildCommand>
 </buildSpec>
 <linkedResources/>
</projectDescription>
`

Comment: Have you tried adding `.classpath` files? If that doesn't work either, I'm officially lost.